# How to get access to the string when foreach-binding to a list of strings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a template like this:

```html
<div data-bind='template: { name: "stringTemplate", foreach: stringCollection() }'> </div>
</div>

<script id='stringTemplate' type='text/html'>

// I want to display string from collection here 
</script>
```

How do I get access to the string object in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a jQuery template, you can use `$data` to refer to the overall object being bound.

So, you would do something like:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
```

or

```
${ $data }
```